# How to run multiple methods in parallel in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have 8 methods in an ASP.NET Console App, like `Fun1()`, `Fun2()`, `Fun3()` ... and so on. In my console application, I have called all these methods sequentially. But now the requirement is I have to do that using parallel programming concepts. I have read about task and threading concepts in Java but completely new to .NET parallel Programming.

Here is the flow of methods I needed in my console app,

[image: Diagram]

As you can see in the diagram, `Task1` and `Task2` should run in parallel, and `Task3` will only occur after completion of the previous two.

The functions inside each task, for example, `Fun3` and `Fun4` for `Task1`, should run sequentially, one after the other.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: you can use Parallel.Invoke(). [For more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: *"...in an ASP.NET Console App..."* -- As far as I know console applications and ASP.NET applications are two different types of projects.

Comment: The `Fun4` should run after the completion of the `Fun3`, or concurrently with the `Fun3`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Not really. Starting with ASP.NET Web API, and continuing with ASP.NET Core, the capability is built in to "self-host" - you can just run as a console app. You could start from the console template and build up to ASP.NET Core as you need it, or start with the ASP.NET Core template and remove everything until you're left with a small console app. It's likely not how you'd do things in production, but the line is really blurred between web and console apps. Very different from the old ASP.NET on .NET Framework days.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias no no Fun4 can run after the completion of fun3.

Comment: @SuprateemBose I edited the question to clarify this point.

Comment: @SuprateemBose what do those methods *really* do? In a web application, parallelism can *hurt* scalability because the code is using a thread/core that could server another request. If `Fun1()` etc execute asynchronous IO it makes sense to use `WhenAll()` to await for the already async methods to complete. If they use the CPU though, running these in parallel means you use 2 threads to server 1 request, halving the number of concurrent requests you can serve. In high traffic systems that's worse than it sounds, because requests will start queueing and spilling to other servers in the farm

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this is, by using [WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-6.0).

To take an example, I have created X number of methods with the name FuncX() like this:

```
async static Task<int> FuncX()
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
    var result = await Task.FromResult(1);
    return result;
}
```

In this case, we have Func1, Func3, Func4, Func5, and Func6.

So we call methods and pass them to a list of Task.

```
var task1 = new List<Task<int>>();

task1.Add(Func3());
task1.Add(Func4());

var task2 = new List<Task<int>>();

task2.Add(Func1());
task2.Add(Func5());
task2.Add(Func6());
```

You have 2 options to get the result:

```
// option1
var eachFunctionIsDoneWithAwait1 = await Task.WhenAll(task1);
var eachFunctionIsDoneWithAwait2 = await Task.WhenAll(task2);
var sum1 = eachFunctionIsDoneWithAwait1.Sum() + eachFunctionIsDoneWithAwait2.Sum();
Console.WriteLine(sum1);

// option2
var task3 = new List<List<Task<int>>>();
task3.Add(task1);
task3.Add(task2);
var sum2 = 0;
task3.ForEach(async x =>
{
    var r = await Task.WhenAll(x);
    sum2 += r.Sum();
});

Console.WriteLine(sum2);
```

This is just example for inspiration, you can change it and do it the way you want.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you could create the tasks according to the diagram, using the [`Task.Run`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method:

```
Task task1 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    Fun3();
    Fun4();
});
Task task2 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    Fun1();
    Fun5();
    Fun6();
});
Task task3 = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
    Fun7();
    Fun8();
});
```

The `Task.Run` invokes the delegate on the [`ThreadPool`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool), not on a dedicated thread. If you have some reason to create a dedicated thread for each task, you could use the advanced `Task.Factory.StartNew` method with the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` argument, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71111345/application-doevents-while-waiting-another-thread/71111774#71111774).

It should be noted that the above implementation has not an optimal behavior in case of exceptions. In case the `Fun3()` fails immediately, the optimal behavior would be to stop the execution of the `task2` as soon as possible. Instead this implementation will execute all three functions `Fun1`, `Fun5` and `Fun6` before propagating the error. You could fix this minor flaw by creating a [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource) and invoking the `Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` after each function, but it's going to be messy.

Another issue is that in case both `task1` and `task2` fail, only the exception of the `task1` is going to be propagated through the `task3`. Solving this issue is not trivial.

---

**Update:** Here is one way to solve the issue of partial exception propagation:

```
Task task3 = Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.IsFaulted)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource tcs = new();
        tcs.SetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
    if (t.IsCanceled)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource tcs = new();
        tcs.SetCanceled(new TaskCanceledException(t).CancellationToken);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
    Debug.Assert(t.IsCompletedSuccessfully);
    Fun7();
    Fun8();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}, default, TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default)
    .Unwrap();
```

In case both `task1` and `task2` fail, the `task3` will propagate the exceptions of both tasks.

Comment: I don't quite understand why `Task.WhenAll()` throws only an exception from `task1`. According to the msdn documentation - If any of the supplied tasks completes in a faulted state, the returned task will also complete in a Faulted state, where **its exceptions will contain the aggregation of the set of unwrapped exceptions from each of the supplied tasks** - then should't it also throw an exception from `task2`?

Comment: @Qwertyluk the `Task.WhenAll` propagates all the exceptions, but the `await` propagates [only the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007781/why-doesnt-await-on-task-whenall-throw-an-aggregateexception).